# C fopen to a specific directory

Tags: c, linux, windows

So i'm trying to create a program that will change the file directory of the fopen() function depending on if the system is Windows or linux.

in my main function i determine the operating system via

```
#ifdef __unix
    printf("linux machine \n");
    windows = false;
    linux = true;
#endif

#ifdef _WIN32   
    printf("windows machine \n");
    windows = true;
    linux = false;
#endif
```

and then in my function where i open the file i do

```
FILE *fp, *fpo;
    if ((windows == true) && (linux == false)) 
    {
        fp = fopen("/temp/coursein/p1-in.txt", "r");
        fpo = fopen("/temp/courseout/p1-out.txt", "w");
    }
    else
    {
        fp = fopen("~/temp/coursein/p1-in.txt", "r");
        fpo = fopen("~/temp/coursein/p1-in.txt", "w");
    }
```

i've tried every variation of "/" "//" "\" "\" i can think of and on linux i get a seg fault and in visual studio i get a Debug Assertion Failed.
Expression: stream != nullptr

Comment: this is quite wrong. `~` does not work in a file name in a C program in Linux. In Windows there is another reason. The crash is because the file was not opened, thus `fp`  or `fpo` is NULL. Use perror to print the error message.

Comment: You might need to use `"C:/temp/coursein/p1-in.txt"` (for an appropriate drive letter) on Windows.  I'm not certain that's necessary, but it is worth a try.  OTOH, I'm certain that testing the result of each `fopen()` before continuing most definitely is necessary.  Programs fail to open files for many reasons; you _must_ assume `fopen()` can fail and react appropriately.

Comment: Why not make your program take filenames from argv? Or even directly access stdin/stdout?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, `CreateFile` resolves the path using the runtime library, which replaces forward slashes with backslashes, and, for a drive-relative path, extracts the drive or UNC share from the process working directory. Opening "p1-in.txt" and creating "p1-out.txt" will fail if the drive or share doesn't have "\temp\coursein" and "\temp\courseout" directories, respectively. Also, "p1-in.txt" has to exist. Also, the Linux example opens the same file twice in "r" and "w" mode, which looks like a mistake.

Comment: @eryksun: what you say sounds familiar - and was why I said "I'm not certain that's necessary".  The point about checking the results of `fopen()` remain valid.  Further, you should probably test before the next `fopen()` since `errno` may be clobbered by the second open - if it is set at all which isn't mandated by the C standard.  Your point about the typo in the Linux file names is good - well spotted.  At best, you get to read an empty file if the names are repeated.  If the file didn't exist, the first call fails, of course.

Comment: Note that it is bad practice to use forward slashes instead of backslashes on Windows; I believe it will work in this particular case, so I don't think that's your problem, but it is a bad habit to get into, because there *are* cases where it *won't* work.

Comment: To clarify the comment on `~`, this is a shell meta-character (like `*`) that's expanded _before_ the program executes.

Comment: You're not checking the result of fopen or errno.  That would have been a better place to start from.

Comment: @Zac: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 3):

You are getting a crash in the linux version most likely because the stream pointers are not checked for `NULL` before they are passed to stream functions.

It is poor programming practice to assume `fopen()` always succeeds. Always check the return value of `fopen()` and many other library functions.

There seems to be a typo in the linux version: `fpo = fopen("~/temp/coursein/p1-in.txt", "w");` should probably be `fpo = fopen("~/temp/courseout/p1-out.txt", "w");`

Furthermore, `fopen` does not expand the initial `~/` to the home directory of the user, the shell does this on command line words, not the Standard C library. In unix, you can use `getenv("HOME")` to retrieve the user's home directory and `snprintf` to compose the filename to open. You could write a wrapper function for `fopen` that would handle system specific behavior and return the stream handle.

There is a simpler fix: you can make the paths relative to the current directory:

```
    fp = fopen("temp/coursein/p1-in.txt", "r");
    fpo = fopen("temp/courseout/p1-out.txtt", "w");
```

or

```
    fp = fopen("coursein/p1-in.txt", "r");
    fpo = fopen("courseout/p1-out.txt", "w");
```

It would work in both linux and windows as long as you run the program from an appropriate directory or use `chdir` to change the current directory in the startup function where you test which OS you run on.

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of ways to go about this, but the key boils down to getting the base directory you need using `getenv`. It will work on both windows and unix. You simply need to check and find the proper name for the environment variable needed under each OS.

For example to begin building a path from the users home directory, you can use the environment variable `HOME` on Linux or `USERPROFILE` on windows.

To set your code up to automatically use the appropriate directory, you will generally use a preprocessor check to check for the OS and then set a define identifying the OS to use throughout the remainder of your code. (you could of course use the same test over and over, but standard practice simply defines an identifier for the OS, like `HAVEWIN` on windows, or `HAVEUNIX` on the various Unix flavors.

I generally break it out into two parts, but you are free to do it all at once, e.g.

```
#if defined (_WIN32) || defined (_WIN64)
 #define HAVEWIN 1
#elif defined (__unix__)
 #define HAVEUNIX 1
#endif

#ifdef HAVEWIN
 #define HOMEENV "USERPROFILE"
#elif HAVEUNIX
 #define HOMEENV "HOME"
#endif
```

For your *pathname separators*, windows will allow you to use the POSIX pathname separator `'/'` to separate your path components, but it can get finicky (technical term) when the path includes `spaces`. Windows pathname resolution behaves better in that case using the normal DOS backslash (which you must escape when building your path).

For example, let's say we are interesting in a file named `testfile.txt` on both windows and Linux that resides in the user's home directory (e.g. `C:\Users\username` on windows and `/home/username` on Linux), e.g.

On windoze:

```
C:\users\david>type testfile.txt
hello windows
```

On Linux:

```
$ cat ~/testfile.txt
hello unix
```

You can build the path to reach each using `sprintf` and a buffer sufficient to hold the components. `#include <limits.h>` provides a `PATH_MAX` constant to insure you have sufficient space for the filename (generally `4096` chars). To build the path you could do something like the following:

```
#include <limits.h>
...
int main (void) {

    char *home = getenv (HOMEENV);
    char filename[PATH_MAX] = "";
    char buf[BUFSIZ] = "";
    FILE *fp;

    if (!home) {
        fprintf (stderr, "user home environment not found.\n");
        return 1;
    }

#ifdef HAVEWIN
    sprintf (filename, "%s\\%s", home, FILENAME);
#elif HAVEUNIX
    sprintf (filename, "%s/%s", home, FILENAME);
#endif
...
```

That pretty much provides basics for doing (in short form) what you are attempting to do with both input and output files. Putting all the pieces together, you could do something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define FILENAME "testfile.txt"

#if defined (_WIN32) || defined (_WIN64)
 #define HAVEWIN 1
#elif defined (__unix__)
 #define HAVEUNIX 1
#endif

#ifdef HAVEWIN
 #define HOMEENV "USERPROFILE"
#elif HAVEUNIX
 #define HOMEENV "HOME"
#endif

int main (void) {

    char *home = getenv (HOMEENV);
    char filename[PATH_MAX] = "";
    char buf[BUFSIZ] = "";
    FILE *fp;

    if (!home) {
        fprintf (stderr, "user home environment not found.\n");
        return 1;
    }

#ifdef HAVEWIN
    sprintf (filename, "%s\\%s", home, FILENAME);
#elif HAVEUNIX
    sprintf (filename, "%s/%s", home, FILENAME);
#endif

    if (!(fp = fopen (filename, "r"))) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file not found '%s'\n", filename);
        return 1;
    }

    if (fgets (buf, sizeof buf, fp))
        puts (buf);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

On windoze:

```
C:\users\david>Documents\src-c\bin\getenv_testfile.exe
hello windows
```

On Linux:

```
$ ./src-c/bin/getenv_testfile
hello unix
```

As mentioned at the beginning, there are a number of ways to put all the pieces together. You may find it cleaner to put all your varying windows/unix defines up at the top so that you do not have any preprocessor conditional in `main()`, e.g.

```
...
#ifdef HAVEWIN
 #define HOMEENV "USERPROFILE"
 #define PATHFMT "%s\\%s"
#elif HAVEUNIX
 #define HOMEENV "HOME"
 #define PATHFMT "%s/%s"
#endif

int main (void) {

    char *home = getenv (HOMEENV);
    char filename[PATH_MAX] = "";
    char buf[BUFSIZ] = "";
    FILE *fp;

    if (!home) {
        fprintf (stderr, "user home environment not found.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    sprintf (filename, PATHFMT, home, FILENAME);

    if (!(fp = fopen (filename, "r"))) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file not found '%s'\n", filename);
        return 1;
    }

    if (fgets (buf, sizeof buf, fp))
        puts (buf);

    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** while this may look a bit cleaner, but this is largely impractical in larger code)

Look over all the answers and comments, and let me know if you have any additional questions.

Comment: There is no issue in the Windows filesystem API with using slash in paths with spaces. However, I generally advise to use backslash for the sake of consistency with command-line parsing and other Windows APIs that don't handle slash as a path separator (e.g. registry paths and using "Local" and "Global" named kernel objects, which are both directly implemented on the NT object namespace, which only supports backslash paths).

Comment: Note that using `char *` strings and functions in Windows is unreliable. Environment variables and filesystem paths are UTF-16 `wchar_t *` strings. The ANSI API uses a lossy encoding to the legacy codepage that will replace unmapped characters with either best-fit matches or question marks. It's not uncommon to pick a user name that can't be encoded in the system ANSI codepage, so if this code is meant for general consumption it's only a matter of time before you get the first bug report.

Comment: The user profile is not a home directory, and is hardly ever an appropriate choice for a base directory.  There are API functions for looking up suitable base directories, e.g., Documents or Application Data.  It is *not* true, for example, that the Documents folder will always be `%USERPROFILE%\Documents`.

Comment: Agreed @HarryJohnston. The intent here was not to suggest *"Hey! Just dump stuff in `%USERPROFILE%` -- that there sounds like a right-fine place to store things..."* No. The intent was to show the use of preprocessor checks and environment usage, simply grabbing a basic environment from each OS that would work -- without bandaiding together any more path components than necessary. (it's a bit funny that Vim actually does use that directory for `_viminfo` and `_vimrc` and Gtk uses it for `.gtk-bookmarks`, where arguably both should go under `%LOCALAPPDATA%`....)

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you are running in your home directory, aka ~

fopen's path is from your current working directory. Thus the tilde is wrong (as mentioned because it is a shell oddity).

fp = fopen("temp/coursein/p1-in.txt", "r");

If you need to move to a particular directory consider chdir (man 2 chdir on Linux). Don't forget the other advice regarding testing fp before you open the output file.

Comment: It's a bad idea to write a program that can only be run in a specific directory.

Comment: Never said that and how in the world did you think that? In fact this modification will work IFF there is a writable "temp" directory wherever it is starts from. A limitation I thought the reader should figure out.

Answer (score 0):

The crash, in both cases, will be because the `fopen()` calls are failing and returning `NULL`, and subsequent code is using them without checking (e.g. to read or write).

The problem under unix is that `~` in a path is expanded by the shell (e.g. in paths typed on the command line) not by the C library.   What you need to do is expand the path yourself.

Fortunately, there are ways to do what you want, but they are typically slightly different under windows and linux.   I won't write the code, but I'll point you at things you can use.

- `getenv()` in `<stdlib.h>` can be used to get expand environment variables.  For example, `getenv("XXX")` will return a pointer (to the first character) of a string that is the expansion of the environment variable named `XXX`, under both windows and unix.   It will return a `NULL` pointer if the environment variable `XXX` does not exist.
- Under Unix, the environment variable named `HOME` typically expands to the user's home directory.
- Under windows, you may get lucky and have a `HOME` environment variable defined.   That's not always true though.  If it's not true, there is usually an environment variable named `HOMEDRIVE` that expands to the home drive (e.g. `"C:"` if the home directory is on the C drive) and another variable named `HOMEPATH` that expands to the users home directory without the drive named appended.
- Under unix, paths may be constructed by adding a `'/'` character and sub-directory name.  e.g.   `"/user/home"`.
- Under windows, paths may be constructed the same way, except windows API functions (which are called by `fopen()`) accept both `'/'` and `'\\'` as path separators.

Also bear in mind that `fopen()` will not construct directories.  For `fopen("/temp/x.dat", "w")` to succeed, the directory `/temp` must already exist, and `fopen()` will only try to create `x.dat` within it.

Note, however, that using environment variables is not considered a particularly good way to obtain the user's home directory - particularly under windows - since the user can change environment variables.    Other means of getting the home directory will be more robust, but also typically be specific to unix or windows (e.g. OS specific API functions, rather than using `getenv()`).   I'll leave finding those function as an exercise.

Regardless of how well you construct your paths, it is still a good idea to check that `fopen()` succeeds before passing the handle it returns to other functions that read and write.

Comment: Please note that "the user's home directory" is not a particularly meaningful concept on Windows.  Generally speaking you want the user's Documents directory or one of the Application Data directories.